# Duplicate Specific Row

Tags: sql

i would like to duplicate the row where the person type is equal to 3 in a sql select

```
╔══════════════╦══════╗
║   Person     ║ Type ║
╠══════════════╬══════╣
║ Jeff Atwood  ║   1  ║
║ Geoff Dalgas ║   2  ║
║ Jarrod Dixon ║   3  ║
║ Joel Spolsky ║   4  ║
╚══════════════╩══════╝
```

expected:

```
╔══════════════╦══════╗
║   Person     ║ Type ║
╠══════════════╬══════╣
║ Jeff Atwood  ║   1  ║
║ Geoff Dalgas ║   2  ║ 
║ Jarrod Dixon ║   3  ║
║ Jarrod Dixon ║   3  ║
║ Joel Spolsky ║   4  ║
╚══════════════╩══════╝
```

Thks!

Comment: Do you just want to **select** that row twice? Or do you want to permanently insert a duplicate row?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't know the answer, but your (now deleted) answer was every bit as valid as the one I gave.  I suggest un-deleting it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: assuming Luis actually wants to _insert_  a second row, not just _select_ it.

Comment: Its not to insert, is just a select

Comment: While asking this type of question request you to provide your try to make your question good.

Answer (score 1):

You may try a union query:

```
SELECT Person, "Type" FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Person, "Type" FROM yourTable WHERE "Type" = 3
ORDER BY "Type";
```

Note that I placed `Type` in double quotes to escape it, under the assumption that `Type` might be a reserved keyword in your version of SQL.

Comment: ... +1 for being faster than Gordon Linoff (while enumerating the columns !)

Comment: @GMB But keep an eye on the stats, Gordon was probably finishing up another question where none of us answered as fast as he did.

Comment: That's for sure...!

Answer (score 1):

I don't like union :) So query without union

```
select a.*
from your_table a
left join (values(1),(2)) b(c)
  on a.type = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`:

```
select t.*
from t
union all
select t.*
from t
where type = 3;
```

I would strongly discourage you from create a table with complete duplicates, but if that is what you want:

```
insert into t (person, type)
    select person, type
    from t
    where type = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

In such situations I use to join a subquery on special condition, this allows to keep all "where" conditions in one place in query:

```
select
  t.Person
 ,t.Type
from t
inner join (
  select 1 as row_type
  union all select 2
) rt on t.Type = 3 and rt.row_type in (1, 2) or rt.row_type = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought of using grouping sets to archive the goal ... but probably the cartesian from @alex-sham is better.

```
with bas as (
    select level type, DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('L','10') person, case when level = 3 then level else null end lv3 from dual connect by level <= 5)
, calc as (
    select type,lv3, GROUPING_ID(type,lv3)gid,min(person) person  from bas
    group by grouping sets(type,(type,lv3)))
select person,type from calc where lv3 is not null or gid = 1;
```